# cordova-debug-adapter Error: Unable to find pid ionic 2

Tags: cordova, angular, visual-studio-code, ionic2

I am developing my app using ionic and i wanted to debug my application on Mobile device not emulator.It works perfectly in Windows but do not launch on ubuntu or macintosh.
I also have usb debugging enabled on device,as i said works perfect in Windows.
This is my ionic info

> Blockquote

```
Cordova CLI: 6.3.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
OS: Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Node Version: v6.4.0
```

This is my launch.json,

```
 {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Android on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "device",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "ionicLiveReload": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Run iOS on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "device",
            "port": 9220,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "ionicLiveReload": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to running android on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "device",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to running iOS on device",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "device",
            "port": 9220,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Run Android on emulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "ionicLiveReload": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Run iOS on simulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9220,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "ionicLiveReload": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to running android on emulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9222,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to running iOS on simulator",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "attach",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "emulator",
            "port": 9220,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Serve to the browser (ionic serve)",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "serve",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "devServerAddress": "localhost",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "ionicLiveReload": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Simulate Android in browser",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            "target": "chrome",
            "simulatePort": 8000,
            "livereload": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Simulate iOS in browser",
            "type": "cordova",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",
            "target": "chrome",
            "simulatePort": 8000,
            "livereload": true,
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late post , but might help someone.

I had the same problem, and the solution was to go to the `**SDK Manager**`
and download the android version of the device that i was trying to run my application on.

Comment: when running the app on your phone you should get popup on phone that ask you to allow the app that you're running to be installed. if you have the  sdk installed